# Why am I getting this error (IndentationError: unexpected indent) when trying to scrape data using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to develop a webscraper that gathers information from StockX on sneakers. Here is my code.

```
 
def SneakersInfoScraper():
    # Basic sneaker information

    time.sleep(2)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

    driver.get("https://stockx.com/nike-air-air-jordan-3-jth")
    Model_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="product-header"]/div[1]/div/h1'
    ).text
    # Retrieves the name of the Model
    print(Model_name)
    print("=" * 50)

    Color_Sneaker = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="detail"][2]/span').text
    # Retrieves the color of the sneaker
    print(Color_Sneaker)
    print("=" * 50)

    Retail_Price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="detail"][3]/span').text
    # Retrieves the release date of the model
    print(Retail_Price)
    print("=" * 50)

    Release_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="detail"][4]/span').text
    # Retrieves the release date of the model
    print(Release_date)
    print("=" * 50)

    OtherPriceInfo = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="gauges"]')

    for Each_Price_Info in OtherPriceInfo:
        Price_Premium = Each_Price_Info.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]'
        ).text

    print(Price_Premium)
    print("=" * 50)
```

It works smooth like butter until it hits the OtherPriceInfo variable and I set up my for loop. In the output, I can see that my formatting gets completely messed up and I don't know why.
The error:

```
...     print("=" * 50)
...     OtherPriceInfo = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="gauges"]')
...     for Each_Price_Info in OtherPriceInfo:
...         Price_Premium = Each_Price_Info.find_element_by_xpath(
...             '//*[@id="root            '//*[@id="root     div/d            '//*[@id="root            '//*[@id="ro
  File "<stdin>", line 27
    '//*[@id="root            '//*[@id="root     div/d            '//*[@id="root            '//*[@id="ro
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     print(Price_Premium)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(Price_Premium)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     print("=" * 50)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("=" * 50)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Can anyone advise on how to prevent this from happening? Is it a python error?

Comment: Posted code `'//*[@id="root"]` doesn't match the error `'//*[@id="root            '`.  Please show us the actual code.

Comment: No I'm not, I run it directly from the file and the output is shown in the shell.

Comment: If you run it directly from the file, why does it say `File "<stdin>"`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I use VSCODE and can run the code line by line. The code that I posted is exactly what I ran. I didn't paste it into a shell.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what happened here, but it was almost certainly *one of* the now-linked duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7DUl.png)

Check both functions, visually both are same in terms of indentataion, but differs logically in terms of space... So it is required to use these type of editors which can show spaces and tab spaces separately...

So check your code once again... This is the issue usually occured with most of the python developers. I found this way to resolve this issue.